# TFS2012 - Manifest of multiple folders with different versions

Tags: tfs, version-control

I'm new to version control systems and have been tasked with revamping our company's version control (small system right now).  We have library files that will get updated, but we also need to support older versions of these libraries for different generations of our product.  Part of my task is to set up an automated unit testing system that will do nightly checkouts, if newer code has been checked in since the last test run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need to keep multiple branches of your libraries in source control, one for each version that will be supported/changed in the future.  Each of these branches should have a build definition created to build the code and then run the unit tests against the code.  The builds can be setup to run in

- CI mode which will build on every checkin
- Gated checkin mode (my personal favorite) which won't commit the checkin until the build and test run completes successfully.

Comment: Can I create a build definition that pulls from a specific version of our library branch and a specific version of our application branch?  This is what I'm looking for

Comment: Yes, you can use the "Get Version" field on the build definition to pull a specific changeset number or label.  For a specific changeset prefix the changeset number with a "C".  For a specific lable prefix the label with "L".